# Maintain state in controller?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am willing to use a client for cassandra db, so I need to initialize it as:

```
client = CQEx.Client.new!
```

I've created two routes, to read and write that points to actions in a controller.

The question is, how would I initialize the client only once and use it every time in the controller's actions?

Shall I create a GenServer and send messages to it from controller actions? so that I can maintain the cassandra client within the GenServer?

Shall I create the client every time I execute the action?!

What's the advice here?

Comment: GenServer vs new client every time depends entirely on your needs, like how many concurrent requests you want to handle and how expensive creating a new Cassandra connection is. You might also want to look into a connection pool using poolboy like Ecto uses, see https://github.com/elixir-ecto/db_connection and https://github.com/devinus/poolboy.

Comment: I need to handle thousands of concurrent requests, I think I've answered my self? :) Why not create a `Task` for each read or write operation? so, each task will run on a separate process, is this a good way to do it (in case I decided not to use GenServer, and create connection each time) ?

Comment: Why create a Task? Each request will already be a new process and will run concurrently with other requests.. unless you want to do tons of read/write operations _per request_. Anyways, @tkowal seems to be right - `cqerl` already seems to be creating a pool of connections so you could just call `Client.new!` directly.

Comment: Do you mean that phoenix it self will create a process for each REST request?

Comment: Yes, Phoenix creates a new process for each request. You can try putting `IO.inspect(self)` in a controller action, send a few requests to it, and see the output in the console.

Comment: Awesome, that's super useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have to dig some more, but it looks like `CQEx.Client.new!` is not actually initializing client and is a little bit misleading.

The implementation https://github.com/matehat/cqex/blob/master/lib/cqex/client.ex#L7 shows that it internally calls `:cqerl.get_client()` and if you take a look at `cqerl` library, it spawns supervisors whith connections, so it might be not necessary to handle the concurrency and safe to just use `get_client` and do work.

Comment: If the library has its own supervision tree and worker processes and you only do one or two queries in your action, this would be totally redundant and obfuscate actual business logic. `cqerl` depends on `pooler`, so it probably manages a pool of workers that are constantly connected.
If you do many concurrent queries in *one* controller action, it might give you some speedup. You have to measure it :)